# How can I change divs and spans in a view

Tags: views, theming

i have an unformatted view that show each element as a row. I want to change the css of some divs an span but i do not know how I can refer to them.
The HTML output is:

```
<div class="view view-venue-view view-id-venue_view view-display-id-page view-dom-id-e95cd3ef12fe312b9c0dced54b3c2820">
<div class="view-content">
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
<div class="views-field views-field-title">
<div class="views-field views-field-field-venue-image">
<div class="views-field views-field-field-venue">
<span class="views-label views-label-field-venue">Address: </span>
<div class="field-content">Some Address </div>
</div>
<div class="views-field views-field-field-venue-date">
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
</div>
</div>
```

For example I want to make the Address Label bold. I have tried to write to the css file 
     #view-label-views-label-field-venue span { //some code} but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how general to refer to items of a view in order to change their css?

Thank you
Stella

Answer (score 0):

If it was `<div id="div-id">` you would use `#div-id {...` in your css.

For a class like `<div class="div-class">` you would use `.div-class {...`

Answer (score 0):

with your html structure span.views-label-field-venue {font-weight:bold;} .